# Python 3.3 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am new to python and using tutorial provided on youtube to learn how to code. I wrote a simple script but its failing giving me a 'str' object not callable on 3rd line when I execute it

```
print = ("Hello World")
MyName = input("What is your name?")
print(MyName)
```

This is identical to the tutorial on youtube but mine is failing for some reason. I know its probably something very simple.

Comment: You are **replacing `print`** with a string on the first line - why?!

Comment: Does the tutorial actually tell you to write `print = ("Hello World")`?  What do you expect that to accomplish?

Comment: Yes the tutorial is identical to what i have, the first line was printing out hello world and the second was to ask for an input and display that.

Comment: @cherissemunja May we see the tutorial? I'm sure you've misunderstood something. If not, you should change the tutorial series. The first line doesn't print anything, it should most likely be `print("Hello World")` instead of `print = ("Hello World")`

Comment: It was my mistake just went back and reviewed again there is actually no = on the print line. Lesson has been noted review code carefully

Comment: The tutorial doesn't seem to acknowledge the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Please make sure to read that too.

Comment: Thank you @ Matthias I will look at this; I was actually just looking up why in python there is use of " and '. I will look at the guide you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print = ("Hello World")
```

Change this to:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.x, `print` is a function which lets you do things like `print("Hello World")` which causes "Hello World" to display on the screen. However, when you do this:

```
print = ("Hello World")
```

... then you are *redefining* `print` to be a string because of the `=`. Later, when you try to use it like a function, you get the error that you do since it is no longer a function.

My guess is that the `=` is a typo, and that you simply need to remove it:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Comment: Thank you very much I just realized in the tutorial there was no =. Lesson learnt review code properly